# Batch function for removing trailing backslashes

Tags: batch-file

I want a function that will remove the last back slash/slashes, now I write this code multiple times:

```
IF %variable:~-1%==\ SET variable=%variable:~0,-1%
```

So I'll have smth like this

```
set var1=C:\Folder\
call :removeTrailingBackSlash var1
```

`echo %var1%` - I should see "C:\Folder" here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET var1=c:\somewhere\\\\\\\\\\\\
CALL :removeTrailingBackSlash var1
ECHO var1=%var1%
GOTO :eof
:removeTrailingBackSlash
IF NOT DEFINED %1 GOTO :eof
SETlocal
CALL SET $_=%%%1%%
IF %$_:~-1%==\ endlocal&CALL SET "%1=%%%1:~0,-1%%"&GOTO removeTrailingBackSlash
GOTO :eof
```

This procedure should remove your trailing backslashes. How it works, I'll leave as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: I did my exercise and found, your splendid  `removeTrailingBackSlash` removes even more than trailing b-slashes :)

Comment: don't you both want to share your secrets here ? :)